# Rainbow Text on an HTML page... each character is a different randomly generated color

Tags: javascript, html, text, colors, random

I would like to be able to create a page using HTML and scripts to display text in which each character is of a different randomly generated color.  With a javascript graphics library that supports the creation and use of RBG colors and the Math.random() method, it is simple to make randomly colored lines/shapes/etc, but I do not know how to apply that to text, let alone how to apply that to each individual character.  Any ideas?

Comment: But a rainbow is not random :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the text generated by your script, or provided to it as HTML?  If the former, try [`<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/canvas_tutorial).  The latter is harder; I would wrap each character in `<span style="color:#rrggbb">` using JavaScript (this will be slow).

Comment: Thanks, <canvas> was the right way to go.  The text resides within a string variable that is defined within the javascript. I am using fillText() method to draw the text to the canvas.  This does, however present another problem, in that I see no way to wrap the text.  Would it be possible to run a CSS script inside the javascript and simply run a loop that uses javascript variables to set random color values inside CSS code for each character of the text?  Thanks, Morgan

Comment: I don't think you can do that with canvas, no.  You're going to have to do word wrapping manually.

Comment: Alright.  Wrapping really isn't that important, it was just an experiment.  I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score -2):

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toSpans(span) {
        var str = span.firstChild.data;
        var a = str.length;
        span.removeChild(span.firstChild);
        for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            var theSpan = document.createElement("SPAN");
            theSpan.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str.charAt(i)));
            span.appendChild(theSpan);
        }

    }

    function RainbowSpan(span, hue, deg, brt, spd, hspd) {
        this.deg = (deg == null ? 360 : Math.abs(deg));
        this.hue = (hue == null ? 0 : Math.abs(hue) % 360);
        this.hspd = (hspd == null ? 3 : Math.abs(hspd) % 360);
        this.length = span.firstChild.data.length;
        this.span = span;
        this.speed = (spd == null ? 50 : Math.abs(spd));
        this.hInc = this.deg / this.length;
        this.brt = (brt == null ? 255 : Math.abs(brt) % 256);
        this.timer = null;
        toSpans(span);
        this.moveRainbow();

    }

    RainbowSpan.prototype.moveRainbow = function () {
        if (this.hue > 359) this.hue -= 360;
        var color;
        var b = this.brt;
        var a = this.length;
        var h = this.hue;
        for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            if (h > 359) h -= 360;
            if (h < 60) {
                color = Math.floor(((h) / 60) * b);
                red = b;
                grn = color;
                blu = 0;
            } else if (h < 120) {
                color = Math.floor(((h - 60) / 60) * b);
                red = b - color;
                grn = b;
                blu = 0;
            } else if (h < 180) {
                color = Math.floor(((h - 120) / 60) * b);
                red = 0;
                grn = b;
                blu = color;
            } else if (h < 240) {
                color = Math.floor(((h - 180) / 60) * b);
                red = 0;
                grn = b - color;
                blu = b;
            } else if (h < 300) {
                color = Math.floor(((h - 240) / 60) * b);
                red = color;
                grn = 0;
                blu = b;
            } else {
                color = Math.floor(((h - 300) / 60) * b);
                red = b;
                grn = 0;
                blu = b - color;
            }
            h += this.hInc;
            this.span.childNodes[i].style.color = "rgb(" + red + ", " + grn + ", " + blu + ")";
        }
        this.hue += this.hspd;

    }
</script>
<center>
    <p id="r3">&copy Copyright 2013 by K45KMT</p>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var r3 = document.getElementById("r3");

    var myRainbowSpan2 = new RainbowSpan(r3, 0, 360, 255, 50, 348);

    myRainbowSpan2.timer = window.setInterval("myRainbowSpan2.moveRainbow()", myRainbowSpan2.speed);

    var colour = "#FF2535";
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: I added your code. You should add some explanations and take some time to familiarize yourself with the markdown system.